# How to prevent deletion of uploaded files from live server when github CI CD pipeline automatically deploy source code to server

Tags: node.js, github, amazon-ec2, deployment, cicd

I am using github Runner to connect with my live aws ec2 instance, My intention was to automatically deploy my changes of my nodejs app to live from github.
The problem I faced is that I have an upload folder with  files inside src/uploads/*, which also have sub directory , Those files also get removed after deployment to live server
I have added path ignore on my yaml file but it doesn't work, Can someone help me to figure out this issue as it wipe of sensitive uploaded images

My yml file is as follows

```
name: CI Live Pipeline

on:
  push:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'src/uploads/**' // This didnt work
    branches: [ main ]
      


jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: server-dev

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2


      - name: Install Nodejs Dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: 'Create env file'
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo PORT="8081" >> .env
          cat .env

      - name: Run Server
        run: npm run start:stage
```

Anyone have a suggestion for fixing this issue?

On aws ec2 source get over write on the folder /reponame/_work/_work/reponame any wipe out my uploads directory